# GET total COUNT of all the count in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

here I have stored procedure in SQL Server wherein it gets the summary count of each entity. But then I wanted to get the overall TOTAL of it so that I can call it from my table.

Heres my stored procedure.

```
    USE [canteen]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getTotalByCostCenter] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @datefrom datetime, 
    @dateto datetime,
    @entity nvarchar(50),
    @canteen int

AS
IF @entity = 'Aquino'
BEGIN
SELECT 'Aquino' as Plant, d.dept_code, d.dept_name, count(c.id) as Total
    FROM all_chrg c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN emp_mstr e
    ON c.emp_id = e.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN department d
    ON e.emp_dept = d.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN entity et
    ON e.emp_entity = et.id
    WHERE et.entity_code IN ('1425')
    AND c.pdate >= @datefrom AND c.pdate <= @dateto
    AND c.plant_tag = @canteen
    GROUP BY d.dept_code,d.dept_name
    ORDER BY d.dept_code
END
ELSE
IF @entity = 'Central Office'
BEGIN
SELECT 'Central Office' as Plant, d.dept_code, d.dept_name, count(c.id) as Total
    FROM all_chrg c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN emp_mstr e
    ON c.emp_id = e.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN department d
    ON e.emp_dept = d.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN entity et
    ON e.emp_entity = et.id
    WHERE et.entity_code IN ('1410')
    AND c.pdate >= @datefrom AND c.pdate <= @dateto
    AND c.plant_tag = @canteen
    GROUP BY d.dept_code,d.dept_name
    ORDER BY d.dept_code
END
ELSE
IF @entity = 'Gabriela'
BEGIN
SELECT 'Gabriela' as Plant, d.dept_code, d.dept_name, count(c.id) as Total
    FROM all_chrg c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN emp_mstr e
    ON c.emp_id = e.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN department d
    ON e.emp_dept = d.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN entity et
    ON e.emp_entity = et.id
    WHERE et.entity_code IN ('1410','1420','1425','1435','1407')
    AND c.pdate >= @datefrom AND c.pdate <= @dateto
    AND c.plant_tag = @canteen
    GROUP BY d.dept_code,d.dept_name
    ORDER BY d.dept_code
END
ELSE
IF @entity = 'PETC'
BEGIN
SELECT 'PETC' as Plant, d.dept_code, d.dept_name, count(c.id) as Total
    FROM all_chrg c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN emp_mstr e
    ON c.emp_id = e.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN department d
    ON e.emp_dept = d.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN entity et
    ON e.emp_entity = et.id
    WHERE et.entity_code IN ('1430')
    AND c.pdate >= @datefrom AND c.pdate <= @dateto
    AND c.plant_tag = @canteen
    GROUP BY d.dept_code,d.dept_name
    ORDER BY d.dept_code
END
ELSE 
IF @entity = 'Lapu-lapu'
BEGIN
SELECT 'Lapu-lapu' as Plant, d.dept_code, d.dept_name, count(c.id) as Total
    FROM all_chrg c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN emp_mstr e
    ON c.emp_id = e.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN department d
    ON e.emp_dept = d.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN entity et
    ON e.emp_entity = et.id
    WHERE et.entity_code IN ('1415')
    AND c.pdate >= @datefrom AND c.pdate <= @dateto
    AND c.plant_tag = @canteen
    GROUP BY d.dept_code,d.dept_name
    ORDER BY d.dept_code
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT CASE WHEN et.entity_code = '1410' THEN
            'Gabriela'
            WHEN et.entity_code = '1420' THEN
            'Gabriela'
            WHEN et.entity_code = '1425' THEN
            'Gabriela'
            WHEN et.entity_code = '1435' THEN
            'Gabriela'
            WHEN et.entity_code = '1407' THEN
            'Gabriela'
            WHEN et.entity_code = '1415' THEN
            'Lapu-lapu'
            WHEN et.entity_code = '1430' THEN
            'PETC'
            ELSE
            'Unknown'
            END as Plant,
    d.dept_code, d.dept_name, count(c.id) as Total
    FROM all_chrg c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN emp_mstr e
    ON c.emp_id = e.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN department d
    ON e.emp_dept = d.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN entity et
    ON e.emp_entity = et.id
    WHERE c.pdate >= @datefrom AND c.pdate <= @dateto
    AND c.plant_tag = @canteen
    GROUP BY CASE WHEN et.entity_code = '1410' THEN
            'Gabriela'
            WHEN et.entity_code = '1420' THEN
            'Gabriela'
            WHEN et.entity_code = '1425' THEN
            'Gabriela'
            WHEN et.entity_code = '1435' THEN
            'Gabriela'
            WHEN et.entity_code = '1407' THEN
            'Gabriela'
            WHEN et.entity_code = '1415' THEN
            'Lapu-lapu'
            WHEN et.entity_code = '1430' THEN
            'PETC'
            ELSE
            'Unknown'
            END,
            d.dept_code,d.dept_name
    ORDER BY Plant,d.dept_code
END
```

Comment: Instead of dumping a lengthy stored procedure in the post, why not create a very simple version of what you are trying to  achieve (taking out all of the complexity) and you'll likely get a better response. People like to help, but will probably be put of by trawling through what you posted.

Comment: It really is not clear what the problem you are having is, however, at a guess, you could try using [`GROUPING SETS`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to get your total, e.g. at the end of each section add `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((d.dept_code,d.dept_name), ())` instead of just `GROUP BY d.dept_code,d.dept_name`

Comment: What I was trying to say is that I need to get all the Total of Total ...

Comment: I would suggest you follow the advice of @GarethD. Use the [GROUPING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178544.aspx) function to distinguish between regular rows and grouped row.

Comment: Why don't you keep a Total variable and keep adding to it as you progress through the SELECTs?

Comment: @TT .. How will I use that keyword `GROUPING` if ever ?? How can I substitute it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
USE [canteen]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getTotalByCostCenter] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@datefrom datetime, 
@dateto datetime,
@entity nvarchar(50),
@canteen int
AS
IF @entity = 'Aquino'
BEGIN
declare @cnt int
SET @cnt=0
SELECT 'Aquino' as Plant, d.dept_code, d.dept_name, @cnt=@cnt+count(c.id) as Total
FROM all_chrg c
LEFT OUTER JOIN emp_mstr e
ON c.emp_id = e.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN department d
ON e.emp_dept = d.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN entity et
ON e.emp_entity = et.id
WHERE et.entity_code IN ('1425')
AND c.pdate >= @datefrom AND c.pdate <= @dateto
AND c.plant_tag = @canteen
GROUP BY d.dept_code,d.dept_name
ORDER BY d.dept_code
END
ELSE
IF @entity = 'Central Office'
BEGIN
SELECT 'Central Office' as Plant, d.dept_code, d.dept_name,     @cnt=@cnt+count(c.id) as         Total
FROM all_chrg c
LEFT OUTER JOIN emp_mstr e
ON c.emp_id = e.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN department d
ON e.emp_dept = d.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN entity et
ON e.emp_entity = et.id
WHERE et.entity_code IN ('1410')
AND c.pdate >= @datefrom AND c.pdate <= @dateto
AND c.plant_tag = @canteen
GROUP BY d.dept_code,d.dept_name
ORDER BY d.dept_code
END
ELSE
IF @entity = 'Gabriela'
BEGIN
SELECT 'Gabriela' as Plant, d.dept_code, d.dept_name, @cnt=@cnt+count(c.id) as Total
FROM all_chrg c
LEFT OUTER JOIN emp_mstr e
ON c.emp_id = e.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN department d
ON e.emp_dept = d.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN entity et
ON e.emp_entity = et.id
WHERE et.entity_code IN ('1410','1420','1425','1435','1407')
AND c.pdate >= @datefrom AND c.pdate <= @dateto
AND c.plant_tag = @canteen
GROUP BY d.dept_code,d.dept_name
ORDER BY d.dept_code
END
ELSE
IF @entity = 'PETC'
BEGIN
SELECT 'PETC' as Plant, d.dept_code, d.dept_name, @cnt=@cnt+count(c.id) as Total
FROM all_chrg c
LEFT OUTER JOIN emp_mstr e
ON c.emp_id = e.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN department d
ON e.emp_dept = d.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN entity et
ON e.emp_entity = et.id
WHERE et.entity_code IN ('1430')
AND c.pdate >= @datefrom AND c.pdate <= @dateto
AND c.plant_tag = @canteen
GROUP BY d.dept_code,d.dept_name
ORDER BY d.dept_code
END
ELSE 
IF @entity = 'Lapu-lapu'
BEGIN
SELECT 'Lapu-lapu' as Plant, d.dept_code, d.dept_name, @cnt=@cnt+count(c.id) as Total
FROM all_chrg c
LEFT OUTER JOIN emp_mstr e
ON c.emp_id = e.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN department d
ON e.emp_dept = d.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN entity et
ON e.emp_entity = et.id
WHERE et.entity_code IN ('1415')
AND c.pdate >= @datefrom AND c.pdate <= @dateto
AND c.plant_tag = @canteen
GROUP BY d.dept_code,d.dept_name
ORDER BY d.dept_code
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT CASE WHEN et.entity_code = '1410' THEN
        'Gabriela'
        WHEN et.entity_code = '1420' THEN
        'Gabriela'
        WHEN et.entity_code = '1425' THEN
        'Gabriela'
        WHEN et.entity_code = '1435' THEN
        'Gabriela'
        WHEN et.entity_code = '1407' THEN
        'Gabriela'
        WHEN et.entity_code = '1415' THEN
        'Lapu-lapu'
        WHEN et.entity_code = '1430' THEN
        'PETC'
        ELSE
        'Unknown'
        END as Plant,
d.dept_code, d.dept_name, @cnt=cnt+count(c.id) as Total
FROM all_chrg c
LEFT OUTER JOIN emp_mstr e
ON c.emp_id = e.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN department d
ON e.emp_dept = d.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN entity et
ON e.emp_entity = et.id
WHERE c.pdate >= @datefrom AND c.pdate <= @dateto
AND c.plant_tag = @canteen
GROUP BY CASE WHEN et.entity_code = '1410' THEN
        'Gabriela'
        WHEN et.entity_code = '1420' THEN
        'Gabriela'
        WHEN et.entity_code = '1425' THEN
        'Gabriela'
        WHEN et.entity_code = '1435' THEN
        'Gabriela'
        WHEN et.entity_code = '1407' THEN
        'Gabriela'
        WHEN et.entity_code = '1415' THEN
        'Lapu-lapu'
        WHEN et.entity_code = '1430' THEN
        'PETC'
        ELSE
        'Unknown'
        END,
        d.dept_code,d.dept_name
ORDER BY Plant,d.dept_code
END
```

Comment: its says that `Must declare the scalar variable "@cnt"` what does it mean @Deepak

Comment: @Anaiah try it again. I just fix the problem